# Cyber-attacks with demand dataset

Tags: data-request, finance, internet, computing

I am looking for a dataset containing a list of cyber-attacks were attackers made a demand (e.g., a [ransom](http://science.slashdot.org/story/16/02/15/2311242/hackers-demand-36-million-from-hollywood-hospital-following-cyber-attack)), with as many following fields as possible:

- date of attack
- duration of attack
- date of demand
- type of demand (if ransom, the amount)
- target
- information on the executers
- whether the demand was met